# What does the phrase "to a shot of yourself" mean here?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "to a shot of yourself" in the following sentence (this is not available online):

> Do you want to cut from your screencast to a shot of yourself
>   speaking?

I have never seen the structure of "cut from something to a shot of oneself".

The quoted sentence describes a function of the video editing and screencast tool, [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/pdfs/user-guides/ScreenFlow-9-User-Guide.pdf).

Comment: In TV speak, **a shot of yourself** is a video of yourself, presumably speaking. So the question asks whether **you** wish to **cut away** (move the camera from) the screen cast (a digital recording of what's on a computer screen) to a video of yourself. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screencast

Comment: Not everything in the language has been written down. To cut from one scene to another is very common.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you want to cut from your screencast to a shot of yourself speaking?

`Cut` here is specifically used with video editing / describing the flow of video, and has the sense of `go`.  "Do you want to cut from your screencast to a shot of yourself speaking?"  means:

> At some point during or at the end of your screencast, do you want the picture or video to go to one which depicts you speaking?

You can use `cut` in this way if you are editing video or audio or describing the flow of edited video or audio, but never in any other situation.

Comment: There is an idiom derived from this use: "cut to the chase", which can be used in any situation.  It means to skip everything except the main point or exciting part, as if some video stream was cutting right to the car chase, which is presumably the climax of the film.